# OpenCV : How to resize a capture?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to show capture at the exact same size. I tried this :

```
// in the class.h
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture capture;
```

and I tried several solutions now.

Number 1: The size doesn't change at all.

```
this->capture.open(0);
or
this->capture.open(filename);

this->capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800);
this->capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600);
```

Number 2: Exception.

```
this->capture.open(0);
or
this->capture.open(filename);

this->capture.read(this->frame);
if (!this->frame.empty())
    cv::resize(this->frame, this->frame, cv::Size(800, 600));
```

Number 3: Exception.

```
this->capture.open(0);
or
this->capture.open(filename);

cv::resize(this->frame, this->frame, cv::Size(800, 600));
this->capture.read(this->frame);
```

None of these work. Any idea how to resize it properly?

Comment: I don't see how it needs any more code. It doesn't work as the videos aren't resized, webcam or file.

Comment: OP edited with tests.

Comment: Does `// Number 3: Exception` mean you are getting an exception? If so waht is it. In 3 it doesn't make any sense to resize a frame before you read it. I agree with a-Jays about the code - it is hard to get the context.

Comment: Yeah, for the 2 also, it means I'm getting an exception.
I can't understand why you need the context since the code is pretty self explainatory. But I guess, some people just want to downvote.

Comment: For the 3rd, I've read a 'Solution' on an OpenCV forum. Guess it was wrong anyway, that's why I put it here also.

Answer (score 5):

For the function `capture.set()` only some options work for some input formats. That means for example that you can not set the FPS for a movie file, but you can skip to a certain frame. On the other hand on a camera input you can do the exact opposite.

So, if you are trying to change the size of your input images while loading a movie you have to use `cv::resize()`. If you are loading a camera input, it might be that this resolution is not supported by the camera. See if you can get images from this camera in this size with other programs.

You can use `cv::resize()` in the following way:

```
this->capture.open(0);
if(this->campture.isOpen()){
 this->capture.read(this->frame);
 if (!this->frame.empty()){
  cv::Mat resized;
  cv::resize(this->frame, resized, cv::Size(800, 600));
  cv::imshow("resized",resized);
 } else std::cout<<"No input frame!"<<std::endl;
 cv::waitKey(5);
} else std::cout<<"No camera detected!"<<std::endl;
```

Comment: and of course cv::waitKey() is needed to actually see anything.

Comment: Indeed, I've edited the post to include the waitKey()

Comment: I updated the OP, where I tested your solution. It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see that part in the OP. What is your error message exactly? Are you showing the correct image?

Comment: Yours would be // Number 2 and I'm getting an exception, which I isolated to the cv::resize() part.
And you might want to say that it's not exactly what you wrote, but I did actually wrote exactly as you did. It's still the same.

Comment: Can you post that exception for me?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFCE7940D in theprogram.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000001FAF80.

Comment: Try the new example in my post. It attempts to handle everything that can go wrong and print the error. Another advice is to take all your references to this and just take the standard simple capture example from OpenCV and try to do the same thing in that program.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can resize a capture, or at least not as you have tried. The `set` function is to set the property (width, height, etc.) not resizing it.

I would suggest you to get the frame and resize each frame:

```
while (true)
{
  cv::Mat frame;
  this->capture >> frame;
  if (frame.empty()) break;
  cv::resize(frame, frame, sizeYouWant);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, the capture is not resized in this way, only the frame. Maybe you should create another capture based on resized frame? `>>` means read...

Comment: How do you base a capture on a frame size ?

Answer (score 1):

```
frame = cv2.resize(old_frame, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```